# Tweepy - TweepError Code 89: Invalid or expired token

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to unfollow people using [tweepy](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/getting_started.html). It worked just fine when I used it earlier. But, then it started to get the  `Code 89: Invalid or expired token` error. I visited https://apps.twitter.com/ page. And, found out, my account access token got revoked. However, I generated *access token* again and tried one more time. It unfollowed another person and again `Error Code: 89`. 
Tried again, setting a time sleep of 60s and same thing happened. 
It unfollow one person and then again `Error Code: 89` and, the access token is revoked automatically again.

```
name = api.me().name
friendlist = api.friends_ids(name)        
followers = api.followers_ids(name)
with open('unfollowed.csv', "w") as f:    
    for suspect in friendlist:
        if suspect not in followers and suspect not in protected_friends:
            try: 
                txt = str(suspect)+", " +"https://twitter.com/%s" % api.get_user(suspect).screen_name
                print(txt)
                f.write(txt+'\n')
                api.destroy_friendship(suspect)
                time.sleep(60)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                time.sleep(60)
                continue

    print("Now, Following, %d(%d)" % (api.me().friends_count, len(friendlist)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increasing sleep time from `60` to `100` did the trick. Obviously, the modified script takes more time to execute. But, it works...

```
name = api.me().name
friendlist = api.friends_ids(name)        
followers = api.followers_ids(name)
with open('unfollowed.csv', "w") as f:    
    for suspect in friendlist:
        if suspect not in followers and suspect not in protected_friends:
            try: 
                txt = str(suspect)+", " +"https://twitter.com/%s" % api.get_user(suspect).screen_name
                print(txt)
                f.write(txt+'\n')
                api.destroy_friendship(suspect)
                time.sleep(100)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                time.sleep(120)
                continue

    print("Now, Following, %d(%d)" % (api.me().friends_count, len(friendlist)))
```